# Case-insensitive REPLACE() in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a field that contains strings such as 'Blah-OVER', 'Blah-OveR', etc. and want to select them without the 'over's.  This only catches the first case (so to speak) and not the others:

```
SELECT field as "before", REPLACE(field, 'OVER', '') as "after"
```

How do I just get them all to say 'Blah-' (preserving the case of what's left) without attempting to cover every case combination with another nested REPLACE function?

Comment: Thanks, Remus, I was looking for the right tag but hadn't tried that combo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a case insensitive collation:

```
SELECT field as "before", REPLACE(field COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI
, 'OVER', '') as "after"
```

See [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) for list of collation names so you choose the one appropiate for your data.

**Update**

Ok, so I missed your actual request (change case of input, not find case-insensitive). The proper solution is... not to change the input but use an adequate collation for your data. If the data must be displayed in a specific format, use display options in the client, eg. CSS `text-transform:uppercase`, not in the server SELECT.

There isn't any built-in SQL function to do this transformation in-place, but is trivial to build a [CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) that uses [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). (On SQL 2005, not on SQL 2000... doh, I need more coffe).

Comment: This syntax is new to me!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server, but maybe it allows you to make use of regular expressions. These usually offer a case-insensitive mode (set via the i-flag).

Otherwise you could uppercase before the replace call, e.g.

```
SELECT field as "before", REPLACE(UPPER(field), 'OVER', '') as "after"
```

Comment: It produces 'BLAH-'. So it changes the input string not only by replacing 'OVER'.

Comment: One site I came across suggested you needed some custom DLL installed to use regexes on 2000.  Also, that returns all the 'blah's as capitalized--sorry, I should've specified that in the question, will edit.

Comment: ⚠: This converts the whole `field` into lower instead of just doing a case insensitive query