# How to check that first one or first two or first three characters in a value is alphabet

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have table with IDNumber column which contains either all numeric or alpha-numeric where either first or first two or first three characters are alphabet. All I want to do remove those alphabets from that value.

Please note that database is in SQL Server 2000.

For example:

```
1430112345679 (This is OK)
PO02456977785 (Remove first two letters)
C035343542654 (Remove first letter)
QPD1236548    (Remove first three letters)
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ... database is sql server 2000 which do not support stuff and patindex functions.

Comment: yes it does. They are ancient and go back to Sybase

Comment: @SyedImranShah . . . The time to upgrade was many, many years ago.

Comment: This looks similar and it was a question that applies to SQL Server 2000 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468359/case-insensitive-replace-in-sql-server-2000

Comment: @CD VA Programmer alphabets are not of exact length. they vary in every record.

Comment: SQL Server 2000? You know what year it is, right? :-)

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive? I'm doubting that you are actually using any version of SQL Server at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want in any supported verion of SQL Server:

```
select idNumber, stuff(idNumber, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', idNumber) - 1, '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4dd00a00638ac3c47ca46978c6124abc) is a db<>fiddle.

In SQL Server 2000 -- which has been unsupported for a long, long time -- you can do something more brute force:

```
select (case when idNumber like '[0-9]%' then idNumber
             when idNumber like '_[0-9]%' then substring(idNumber, 2, len(idNumber))
             when idNumber like '__[0-9]%' then substring(idNumber, 3, len(idNumber))
             when idNumber like '___[0-9]%' then substring(idNumber, 4, len(idNumber))
             . . . -- however many clauses you need
        end)
```

or using `LIKE`:

```
select (case when left(idNumber, 1) between '0' and '9' then idNumber
             when substring(idNumber, 2, 1) between '0' and '9'
             then substring(idNumber, 2, len(idNumber))
             when substring(idNumber, 3, 1) between '0' and '9'
             then substring(idNumber, 3, len(idNumber))
             when substring(idNumber, 4, 1) between '0' and '9'
             then substring(idNumber, 4, len(idNumber))
             . . . -- however many clauses you need
        end)
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you very much. Your query works.

Answer (score 4):

`PATINDEX` is available in SQL Server 2000. Use it:

```
SELECT val, SUBSTRING(val, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', val), LEN(val)) AS newval
FROM (
    SELECT '1430112345679' AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PO02456977785' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C035343542654' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'QPD1236548'
) AS x
```

[image: Result]

Comment: PATINDEX works when using SSMS of 2008 and above but do not work when using query analyzer of SQL server 2000

Comment: Nope, that would be impossible. Just double checked using SQL 2000 query analyzer and it works.